# Why can't we think of mechanism to save people in case of airplane problem?

Tags: aircraft-design, safety, security

Given it is 21st century, why we can't think of mechanism which will save people in case there is problem with the airplane during flight? e.g. so that cases like MH370 don't happen?

Is this really such a difficult engineering problem?

Comment: I'm sure we could if we were willing to spend 100 times more on tickets and have all of the versatility taken out of it.

Comment: What do you mean? Lives are saved every day because such safety mechanisms already exist.

Comment: Why can't we think of mechanism to save people in case of *insert random human activity here*?

Comment: BTW. Every time I fly, before takeoff flight attendants perform obligatory lecture about "mechanisms that save people in case of airplane problem?" - oxygen masks, life rafts, emergency exits etc...

Comment: [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16545/62) and [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9564/62) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

There are, as many others pointed out, many thousands of systems, saving the aircraft.

But I assume you mean things like ejection seats or parachutes for passengers:

There is indeed already a mechanism to save the passengers of a plane. Not for airliners, but for general aviation planes. It's called the [Ballistic Recovery System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_Recovery_Systems) (BRS). Cirrus built it into their Cirrus Aircraft and named it Cirrus Airframe Parachute System (CAPS).

[image: CAPS Deployment]

[Source](http://www.aero-news.net/index.cfm?do=main.textpost&id=f814a84b-0d92-4e6a-8609-c413fda302fc)

Comment: There are millions of safety mechanisms in aviation and they save lives every day.

Comment: You are right of course.